Turn the parallel railway lines vector files into polygon files
I have two parallel lines (line vector shapefile) which represent railways, could you tell me how to turn it into a polygon file, so that it can be used as polygon shapefile  to extract the digital terrain model data on the area along the route?

There are two methods I have considered:

I tried to use line to polygon on QGIS, but the result is unwanted as shown by the below picture.



The other approach I attempt to use is to draw lines on the endpoints of the two parallel lines, so that they can form into a quadrilateral. But I am not sure how to do it.


The link of my shapefiles is attached in here, could our experts give me suggestion?
link to shapefiles

Can't you just use "Create Buffer" on the lines?

Here are my roads:

We are going to close the 2 ends of the roads. Make sure you set the Snapping Settings to make sure your start at the end of each road:

Use the dissolve tool from the Processing Toolbox:

Here is the result:

From the Processing Toolbox use the Lines to Polygons tool:

Here is the result:

Make sure you use the Snapping Settings to make sure the line close properly.
Findings about your data:
After loading one side of the rail,

I went ahead to use the topology checker to validate the lines

Here are the result:

In short there are too many errors to be able to create the polygons.
Here, the lines do not close:

Here you have a few errors as well

Here you have a gap and an additional small line:

I suggest that you edit your lines manually first by moving the vertices using the vertex tool to make sure your lines are continuous. then you will be able to use the method I have shown you earlier.


@KaiyuanZheng: What should I do when someone answers my question?

@KaiyuanZheng To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Hi, thanks for your detailed answers. I have followed your advice. But it still finally turn into the polygon shape shown on the second pictures of my question. I guess it is probably the result from the vertices which originally divide the lines into different segments according to their attribute values. Could you tell me how to address this problem? I have used the dissolve function but it did not work as expected.

Can you share your lines?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S88tg8xsLp2_pFMu_kkDRDJVK0zpBZCD/view?usp=drive_link

Check the update and findings about your data. Hope this helps.


Copy the two lines to a new shapefile
edit the layer and add two new connecting line manualy to close the two open gaps. Make sure to snap.
Merge the 4 lines. You know have a closed polyline
convert the now closed polyline to a polygon

